# Subclass UIViewController and UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller, subclassing, pushviewcontroller

Here is my problem:

1. ViewControllerA is a subclass of BaseViewController
2. ViewControllerB is a subclass of BaseViewController

If ViewControllerA pushes to ViewControllerB everything works fine.

The problem is when ViewControllerB pops back to ViewControllerA, ViewControllerA's pushViewController calls no longer work.

I've tested with breakpoints and the line of code with pushViewController is being called, it seems that ViewControllerA is no longer inside the navigationController.

What am I doing wrong here? If needed I can post actual code but since its a client project I'd need to scrub it first.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Try Release / Retain checking for ViewControllerA. Possibly, the ViewControllerA is released from its NavigationController... But it's hard to help you without seeing your code

Comment: btw, are you using animation when you push ViewControllerB back onto the navController? I've seen a similar problem but only when animation is disabled.